# The exe in debug folder dosen't work when I move it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, exe

I need to send my c# app to my classmate but when I execute the .exe file in the Debug folder of the project the app open normally.

The problem occur when I copy the "Debug" folder to my desktop, and I do the same thing, it dosen't work. Nothing happen.

It is a big project with a lot of code. The app open normally when I execute it in C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\UpdateMyDb2\UpdateMyDb\bin\Debug but when I copy Debug for exmple to the desktop it dosen't work. C:\Users\MyName\Desktop

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: Do you have relative references to files (dlls?) elsewhere?

Comment: Your .exe likely has a number of dependencies.  If you don't copy the DLL files along with the EXE, it will not work because it cannot resolve the dependencies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it does not provide any substantial details required to solve it.

Comment: I didn't post code beacause I was sure that the problem wasn't about  code, as I have explained the app worked perfectly fine. The other answer helped me a lot, I forgot one reference to an image in an other folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Your .exe likely has a number of dependencies. If you don't copy the DLL files along with the EXE, it will not work because it cannot resolve the dependencies. – Josh Knack"

My problem was that I copied only the Debug folder but in my project I have references to images that are in the Image folder who is not inside the Debug folder.

I just copied the Image folder next to the Debug folder. Now it works.